# right click in explorer attach directory to exe

Tags: c#, contextmenu, windows-shell

I am trying to write a program, so that when in explorer, the user can right click on a file, my program starts, but when it starts the directory that the program was called from

"is inserted somehow into my program"
, then i can do what i want with it and its contents.

Im new to all the windows classes/namespaces. i have figured out how to deal with folders/files and a simple gui (wpf), and with [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/10104/add-a-context-menu-to-the-windows-explorer)! have figured out how to separately register my prog in the reg, but a little unsure of the next step.

Another question, because the windows platform changes over time (the link is dated 2005 i think), is the method of registering an exe like in the link still the best way to go about it?

Comment: @nineberry cheers

Comment: When following the article on codeproject, add "%1" in double quotes to the Path to the executable, e.g. `c:\Path\myapplication.exe "%1"`. The name of the file or folder that the context menu was invoked on will then be passed to the application as a commandline paramter. You can then access it via `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`in the application.

Comment: nice, will try cheers